# Cauchy implies Wilson

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to solve this problem

> Use the Cauchy's Theorem to prove the Wilson's Theorem.

This is a problem that I have to solve for my modern algebra class. I tried to use p-subgroups and the group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to find something useful, but I totally fail. If someone can help me to solve this problem I will be thankful.

I saw in class the proof of Cauchy's Theorem using action of groups, I think something like this will help to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: For different proofs of Wilson's theorem see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Proofs) (they use Lagrange's theorem, though, not Cauchy's theorem).

Answer (score 3):

There is a proof of *Wilson's theorem* using the *Cauchy–Frobenius theorem* on counting orbits:
there exist $(p-1)!$ cyclic permutations of $p$ points. The cyclic
group $C_p$ acts on them by conjugation, which we can view geometrically as rotation. There are $p-1$ fixed cycles, hence *Cauchy–Frobenius* implies that $(p-1)!\equiv p-1 \bmod p$ (for details see [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFQQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.brandeis.edu%2F~gessel%2Fhomepage%2Fslides%2Fcomb-cong.pdf&ei=O6MKVZvHLIisOvHogaAC&usg=AFQjCNHmNMdqDJiE8NyVv3JnTwyY5dwfXg&bvm=bv.88528373,d.ZWU)).